# mlrun, remove files, 'Unauthorized path'

Tags: command, mlrun

I am administrator (with full privilege's in Iguazio\MLRun solution) and I have to clean environment. I would like to remove old accounts and delete files in v3io file systems (which was created under different user accounts). I used standard `rm -rf` command and I got 403 error message:

```
MLRunAccessDeniedError('Unauthorized path')
```

Some ideas?

Comment: Do you have also privilege's Application Admin, and other *Admin?

Comment: Yes, I do. I have all roles exclude '*Read Only'

Comment: Did you use https://www.iguazio.com/docs/latest-release/users-and-security/users/ (I think last note on the page)?

Comment: I tested it and It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create root admin account (for account creation the role 'Security Admin' is mandatory) and then you need to setup UID in the root admin account, see https://www.iguazio.com/docs/latest-release/users-and-security/users/ (see the last note on the page 'Accessing projects and other files of absent users').